# Getting error while trying to install Hyperic server

Tags: linux, centos, hyperic

I am trying to install the latest version of Hyperic (4.6.6) on centos machine and getting this error.

```
>        /home/hq/agent-4.6.6/bin/hq-agent.sh start Installing the server... Unpacking server to: /home/hq... Creating server
> configuration files... Using "small" installing profile... Copying
> binaries and libraries to server installation... Copying server
> configuration file... Copying server db-upgrade files... Copying
> server libs... Setting up server database... Loading taskdefs...
> Taskdefs loaded Loading taskdefs... Taskdefs loaded
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- An ERROR occurred, the installation cannot continue. FATAL EXCEPTION
> at /home/hq/hyperic-hq-installer-4.6.6/installer/data/setup.xml:523: :
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
> /home/hq/hyperic-hq-installer-4.6.6/installer/data/setup.xml:532: The
> following error occurred while executing this line:
> /home/hq/hyperic-hq-installer-4.6.6/installer/data/setup.xml:777: The
> following error occurred while executing this line:
> /home/hq/hyperic-hq-installer-4.6.6/installer/data/setup-db-MySQL.xml:16:
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
> /home/hq/hyperic-hq-installer-4.6.6/installer/data/setup-db-hibernate.xml:94:
> org.hibernate.tool.hbm2x.ExporterException: Errors while performing
> Hbm2DDLExporter
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Deleting temporary JRE
```

I have already looked for the DB connection and everything is fine. I tried to google search, but didn't find any help anywhere.

I know you might need more info, so feel free to comment and I will update whatever I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the Mysql Version.

I was using mysql version 5.5 and Hyperic somehow wasn't supporting it.

I tried the installation with the Mysql Version 5.1, and it worked like charm.

Hope this post will help someone who is trying to get a solution for this.